# rollup with limit?

Tags: mysql, limit, rollup

I'm having trouble with one of my MySQL queries:

```
SELECT id,Portfolio,Agency,Program,Objective,billion1,value11_12,
    Proportion1,billion,value12_13,Percentage,Difference,
    Diff_Percent,PIT,TOS,Actual_PIT,Actual_TOS,SUM(billion),SUM(Percentage),
    SUM(PIT),SUM(TOS),SUM(Actual_PIT),SUM(Actual_TOS)
FROM budget_table
GROUP BY 'sum(Billion)'
WITH ROLLUP
LIMIT 0,100
```

The query works but I can't get the limit to work with the rollup. You can see the results of the query at [BudgetAus](http://budgetaus.net/results.php?Page1=001-100&submit=Show#All)

It is totalling all results rather than the first 100 which is what I am now trying to achieve. I have also tried just using LIMIT 100 but can't get anything to work. I tried using EXPLAIN (for the first time) in MySQL on the database and it said that the query executed although I didn't see any results- but as I've never used it before I wasn't sure what to look for. I'm new to programming and use WAMP rather than a CLI.

I'm also not sure whether to start my limits from 0 or 1?

Comment: I think it reflects poorly on the site and is discouraging to new coders when people when legitimate questions get such immature responses. I guess I expect better from Stack Overflow.

Comment: When you postet your question and code, the code wasn't displayed as "code" , ergo, it wasn't readeble. And that's what i meant with my commnet.

Comment: Really, well I doubt it would have made much difference to whether or not you would be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

`SUM()` operators can't be used in the `GROUP BY` expression, as `SUM()` is an aggregate operator, and hence makes no sense inside a `GROUP BY`

Therefore you should be using `id`, or some other field, for the `GROUP BY`.

The second parameter to `LIMIT` (the offset parameter) starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: `LIMITs start at 1, not 0` --- uhm, no

Comment: You're right. `LIMIT 1` and `LIMIT 1,0` mean the same. `LIMIT 0` returns no records. I've clarified my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answers people, I was called away on a personal emergency but finally got back to this today. The basic issue with this query was that I was not targeting my results for ROLLUP using a variable like in all the others. I was using LIMIT.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY 'sum(Billion)'
```

This does not group by each distinct value of the Billion column.  This groups by a single value, the constant string literal `'sum(Billion)'`.  So you'll get one group, because all rows have the same value when you use a constant string literal as your grouping expression.

Take the quotes off when you put an expression in the GROUP BY column.

Then you'll find that this is not a valid expression for grouping anyway.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I was just trying different things to see if I could get the query to work, not realising that you can't use GROUP BY and LIMIT together.

Comment: I think the other issue was that the aggregate function executes prior to the application of the LIMIT which is why it was not working even without the GROUP BY modifier.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I wrote above.

Comment: Ok Bill. I am not sure whether I understood your explanation. I use the sum function in some GROUP BY statements in my site and it works as intended.

Comment: I was trying to explain that the reason my query was not working as intended was because the LIMIT is applied after the sum function was executed.

Comment: But my point was that a quoted string `'sum(Billion)'` is not a sum function.  It's a string.

Answer (score 0):

My son (who is around here somewhere but I don't know his username) decided he wanted to solve this for me today and provided the following solution:

//Get the main result set
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM budget_table ORDER BY Percentage DESC LIMIT 0,100 ");

//Build an array of the ids for the result set
  $ids = array();
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

//Get id for each row and add to the ids

for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) $ids[] = mysql_result($result, $i, "id");

//Join the ids into a string for use with IN()

$ids_str = implode(",", $ids);

//Get the sums for only the ids of the resultset above

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(billion),SUM(Percentage),SUM(PIT),SUM(TOS),SUM(Actual_PIT),SUM(Actual_TOS) FROM budget_table WHERE id IN($ids_str)");